# Блокировка нажатий JS

Tags: javascript

Блокирую нажатие f12 и комбинаций по Тиму ctrl+shift+I от открытия инспектора кода, всё бы ок, на Windows работает
А как сделать это на Mac? Ведь тут другие клавиши, а именно

```
alt(или option)+command+I
alt(или option)+command+U
alt(или option)+command+C
alt(или option)+command+J
```

Как для них прописать условие блокировки?
Для Windows использую:

```
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: А открытие через соответствующий пункт меню тоже блокируете? Если нет, то зачем вообще стараться?

Comment: @Yaant Всё блокирую, не переживайте. Лучше на вопрос ответьте

Comment: подобные блокировки не работают.. когда ставишь курсор в адресную строку и жмешь f12.  так что я думаю что  бессмысленно.  проверял на примере фигмы, и так далее

Comment: @СергейПетрашко Тогда как можно защитить часть кода? У меня там ссылка на туб видео, надо сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог получить прямую ссылку фрейма

Comment: @Дмитрий, никак - если ты что-то отправил на клиент - это доступно

Comment: @grundy ммм, оно может быть доступно, но в зашифрованном виде. Не знаешь - не пиши

Comment: @Дмитрий, оно зашифровано, только пока ты не используешь его, при использовании ты сам же его и расшифруешь :)

Comment: @grundy Я читал на хабре про способы шифрования, но они у меня не сработали. Почитай ту статью, если найдёшь. Думаю, будет интересно

Comment: @Дмитрий, можешь поискать скинуть :) иначе нельзя будет гарантировать что будет именно та статья про которую ты говоришь. Кроме того, наверняка в ней же было написано, что это ничего не гарантирует.

Comment: @grundy не гарантирует, но в какой-то степени защищает, хотя-бы от средних пользователей

Comment: @Дмитрий, Ну так об этом речь и была, кто захочет - в любом случае получит, если это на клиенте уже.

Comment: @Grundy Меня не интересуют размышления по этому поводу, меня интересует конкретный ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: Он тебе дан - заплюсованный комментарий, продублирую, на всякий случай :) _никак - если ты что-то отправил на клиент - это доступно_

Comment: ТУТ ЕСТЬ ХОТЬ КТО-ТО, КТО МОЖЕТ ОТВЕТИТЬ НА ПОСТАВЛЕННЫЙ ВОПРОС?

Comment: Шифруй, не шифрую, все равно получишь... не получится, кароче говоря. Если заблокировать в браузере все, что можно, есть снифферы, которые дадут тебе прямую ссылку на твой ютюб и все остальное. Во вторых, консоль можно отрыть из меню браузера, а там есть вкладка network, в которой видны все запросы, в том числе и ютюб. Советую не заниматься блокировкой таких вещей, они бесполнезны.

Comment: Тогда как защитить контент на сайте? Я точно знаю, что это возможно, потому что например Mail.ru в этом году делали новогодние поздравления и их поздравление невозможно было скачать. Там бы как-будто пустой файл, который был в каком-то странном формате, в итоге его не удалось скачать ни через какие инструменты инспектора

Comment: @Дмитрий, если у тебя есть пример, который ты хотел бы повторить - стоит его добавить. Новогодние поздравления mail.ru, вот эти имеются ввиду? https://newyear.mail.ru/?newname=QQQQQ&hobby=sladkoe&action=kushay&age=7&g=m

Comment: @Grundy Да, верно

Comment: @Дмитрий, можешь задать вопрос, как это реализовано :) но в любом случае ссылки все видны и свободно доступны

Comment: @Grundy Попробуй его скачать

Comment: @Дмитрий, я уже посмотрел :) он грузит частями по несколько секунд :)ты можешь увидеть запросы за файлами во вкладке `network`

Comment: список загружаемых видео файлов хранится в файлах `manifest.m3u8`, например: `/video/man/_/h_sladkoe/a_kushay/7/manifest.m3u8` можешь сравнить эти адреса с теми, что показываются во вкладке `network`

Comment: @Grundy Прям .mp4 достать сможешь? Скачать и запустить у себя на ПК

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105577/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 2):

Для определения, что нажата клавиша `Command` нужно проверить свойство [`.metaKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey)

Для определения, что нажата клавиша `Option` нужно проверить свойство [`.altKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey)